# Android studio, I do have a gap between a picture and screen end

Tags: android-studio, resize

Here is the screenshot with the code and gap issue , I tried get it done with the
match_parent and it does not work, please advice how can I fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAVUr.png)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="275dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:src="@drawable/slide_show"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.545"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: What do you mean? I see the image at the bottom of the screen. You want to remove the space between the button and the image ?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what is wrong with your layout and how you want it to look. Also, from the screenshot you posted, it looks like you have multiple ConstraintLayouts in your Activity_Main.xml.  For a simple layout such as this, you would want to have the entire xml be a ConstraintLayout, with your text box, Button, and ImageView within it.

Comment: what is the issue?